# How to make a heat map with values given by coordinates in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, plot

I have a `10018x3` matrix, where each row represents a measurement at a particular `(x, y)` coordinate. That is, the 1st column contains all the `x` values, the 2nd has all the `y` values, and the 3rd contains all the measurements.

[The matrix is available here.](http://justpaste.it/fd0f)

I now wish to plot the heat map of the measurements. How should I do that?

---

My attempt, although maybe stupid, is to do `scatter3(x, y, z)`, which renders me this
[image]

Although I can see the trend, yet what I am wishing for is this.
[image]

Comment: Do the data points have any particular structure? Could you interpolate the data onto a grid and plot the heat map of that?

Comment: This probably isn't what you're looking for, but a quick and dirty solution is to do an `imshow` on your measurements vector after reshaping (you'll have to reshape by how you x,y was gathered: row/col maj). You can mess with the colormap etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also interpolate using `TriScatteredInterp` and create a contour plot:

```
x=linspace(min(data(:,1)),max(data(:,1)),150);
y=linspace(min(data(:,2)),max(data(:,2)),150);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
F=TriScatteredInterp(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3)-1);
contourf(X,Y,F(X,Y),100,'LineColor','none')
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I want. This replicates the heat map in my simulation software exactly. Thanks a lot! P.S.: my MATLAB R2013b warns that `TriScatteredInterp` will be removed in the future release and suggests me to use `scattered =Interpolant` instead.

Comment: I first used `interp2` and Matlab told me it would be replaced soon by `TriScatteredInterp`! (Using 2012b) Seems like they can't make up their mind.

Answer (score 2):

I used `scatter3` like you did, but you can specify the size of each point as well as the colours for each marker that belong to the colour map.  Once I did that, I set the view so that I'm looking straight above.

Try this code.  This is assuming that your data is stored in a matrix called `data` and in that structure that you just talked about earlier:

```
% Set colour map
colormap(jet);
% Make 3D plot with filled circles coloured in the scheme of the 
% measurements
scatter3(data(:,1), data(:,2), data(:,3), 30, data(:,3), 'filled');
% Set the azimuth and latitude to look directly above
view(0,90);
colorbar; % Throw in the colour bar.
```

This is what I get:

[image]