# How to plot two variables with occurances

Tags: image, matlab, plot

I am stuck up with this problem.I have two variables,velocity and resistivity and occurrences of these two.
3184 1.75 16

3244 1.78 12

4200 2.08 10
....  ..   ..

I have tried with contour but it requires 2,2 matrix.

Comment: I want 2D,data to represent the surface.

Comment: You can be a bit more polite in asking what you want. Your post had basically no information. You didn't tell me you wanted a surface plot.  You can't achieve what you want unless you have a 2D grid of points which you don't have.  I'll leave this question for someone else to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a post by a [previous poster - David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505417/how-to-make-a-heat-map-with-values-given-by-coordinates-in-matlab/23505717#23505717), this is what I would recommend.  Assume that your matrix is in a variable called `data`:

```
x=linspace(min(data(:,1)),max(data(:,1)),150);
y=linspace(min(data(:,2)),max(data(:,2)),150);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
F=TriScatteredInterp(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3)-1);
contourf(X,Y,F(X,Y),100,'LineColor','none')
```

This should give you what you desire.

Comment: NO,what I want is 2d,colors to be proportional to Z.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`scatter`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html):

```
scatter(data(:,1), data(:,2), [], data(:,3), 'o', 'filled'); %// color indicates
%// number of ocurrences
colormap(jet(256)) %// desired colormap
colorbar %// show color scale
```

Example:

[image]